# Problem of different x-axis position when using grid.arrange and legend on bottom

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have to arrange two plots with same axes next to each other and did this with ggplot2 and `grid.arrange`. Because of a more tidy representation, the legends have to be placed bottom. Unfortunately some times the left plot has more legend entries than the right one and therefore needs a second line, yielding x-axes on different y positions. Therefore it does not only look untidy, the aim of being able to compare these plots is not fulfilled anymore.

Can anybody help?

```r
plot_left <- some_ggplot2_fct(variable,left) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+ 
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(size = 0.5, linetype="solid", colour ="black"))

plot_right <- some_ggplot2_fct(variable,right,f)+ 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+ 
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(size = 0.5, linetype="solid", colour ="black"))

# adjust y axis for more easy compare
upper_lim <- max(plot_Volume_right$data$value, plot_Volume_left$data$value)
lower_lim <- min(plot_Volume_right$data$value, plot_Volume_left$data$value)
plot_Volume_left <- plot_Volume_left + ylim(c(lower_lim, upper_lim))
plot_Volume_right <- plot_Volume_right + ylim(c(lower_lim, upper_lim))

# Arrange plots in grid
grid.arrange(plot_Volume_left, plot_Volume_right,
             ncol = 2, 
             top = textGrob(strTitle, 
                            gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Raleway", fontsize = 15, font = 2)))
```

In the picture you can see the result:
[image]

Do you now an easy way to solve this without too much change in code? (The underlying framework is quite large)

Comment: You could try `ggarrange` from the [egg package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/index.html) instead of `grid.arrange`. In my experience it does a really good job at aligning axes. See [some examples here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html).

Comment: Thanks you very much, solved my problem using `gtable` instead of `grid.arrange` and binding the plots manually.